# Incompatible element type Set<String> for collection of String

Tags: apex, customsetting

I need to retrieve a set of Record Type Names from a list Custom Setting `WEID__c` so that I can check that the list includes an Opportunity's Record Type Name, before updating the Opportunity in my Class.

My Custom Setting record's name is the name of the Record Type, while the value is the Record Type Id, which is not needed in this instance so I'm trying to use `keyset()` to retrieve the record's names.

```
global void updOpportunityCloseDates() {

    Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> RT = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    Map<String, WEID__c> weRTs = WEID__c.getall();
    Set<String> validRecordTypes = new Set<String>();

    validRecordTypes.add(weRTs.keyset());

}
```

The above causes the error

> Incompatible element type Set for collection of String

How should I populate my set `validRecordTypes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `add()` method in `Set` collection is used to add a single element to the `Set` collection.

But `keyset()` method on a `Map` return a `Set` of element which is more than one.

So you should be using

```
validRecordTypes.addAll(weRTs.keyset());
```

where `addAll()` method takes a collection of elements(`List` or `Set`) and add all the elements.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use addAll() method like `validRecordTypes.addAll(weRTs.keyset())`.
add() method is used when you want to add a single element and addAll() method is used when you want to add a set or list elements to the set.

You can also define and initialize your set like shown below -

```
Set<String> validRecordTypes = new Set<String>(weRTs.keyset());
```

Comment: It should be Set<String> validRecordTypes = new Set<String>(){weRTs.keyset()};

Comment: @VigneshwaranG ,please refer this link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm

Comment: Sorry got confused with map initialization with this. Thanks for clearing up.